# Showing Percentages in dc.js Row Charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a pie chart that I have converted to a row chart to make it more readable.

In the label for the row chart entries, I want to be able to report on the percentage breakdown for each row (as one could with a pie chart using the start and end angles).

I'm not sure how to add the percentage to the label though. Is this possible?

Comment: This should be possible. Can you post some good and we'll see if we can figure out how to make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this will work. In your row chart definition just add this property

```
.label(function(d){
            return d.key + " : " + d.value + " - " +(d.value / ndx.groupAll().reduceCount().value() * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
        });
```

This will give you something like this on the resulting horizontal bars

> Active : 267 - 50.38%

You can customize this code to suit your needs.